# Run Function before heroku restart

Tags: python, python-3.x, heroku

Is there a way to run a function before heroku automatically restarts a dyno? I have a hobby dyno running a discord.py bot and would like to run a function before the dyno restarts. I have already tried to use atexit, but it doesn't work.

Comment: This question can probably be answered in the documentation of Heroku.

Comment: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#graceful-shutdown-with-sigterm
a `SIGTERM` is sent when the Dyno wants to be restarted. You need to handle that signal event.

Answer (score 0):

If the restart happens at set times, you could look into the schedule module for Python (https://pypi.org/project/schedule/).

i.e.

```
import schedule
import time

def job():
    print("Running...")

schedule.every().day.at("11:30").do(job)

while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: The restart does not happen at a set time. https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#restarting "The cycling happens once every 24 hours (plus up to 216 random minutes, to prevent every dyno for an application from restarting at the same time)."

Comment: Restarts also happen for other reasons, e.g. when deploys happen, when underlying hardware fails, when environment variables ("config vars") change, ... none of that follows a predictable schedule.

Comment: Ok, I did not know it was just a suggestion.